# How to mix pseudo class valid/invalid with Angular form control validator?

Tags: css, angular, forms, pseudo-class

I'm using an Agular form control to control a "select" validity.
When said "select" is invalid, class "ng-invalid" can be found on the "select".
Class "ng-valid" is, when "select" is valid.

However, pseudo class remains ":valid" either way.
The problem is I'm using a third party library for style which is based on pseudo classes to handle style.

Take a look at this example,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xypbcc

I'd like that the pseudo class :invalid apply (and it's css style), when class is "ng-invalid", when select is empty.
(I know I could add the required to the select element, but I actually have other validators in my real use case)

Thanks

Comment: select.ng-dirty.ng-valid {
  color: #000;
  background:blue;

}


select.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
  color: #000;
    background:red;

}
check this out

Comment: you are changing css to apply style.
I have no hand on the style library handling the style and it is using pseudo class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easy way is copy the .css of inactive to .ng-invalid

A work-around is use [setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) You can use a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[invalid]"
})
export class InvalidDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription$: any;
  @Input("invalid") checkAtFirst: boolean = false;
  constructor(private control: NgControl, private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription$ = this.control.statusChanges.subscribe(res => {
      this.el.nativeElement.setCustomValidity(res == "INVALID" ? "error" : "");
    });
    if (this.checkAtFirst && this.control.invalid)
      this.el.nativeElement.setCustomValidity("error");
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The directive inject in the constructor the ngControl (the input) and the elementRef (the HTMLElement) and subscribe to statusChange. I use the input if you want to check at first

So you use like

```
 <select invalid=true formControlName="fcselect">
//or
 <select invalid formControlName="fcselect">
```

You can see the example in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftskzt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with enabling the [Native DOM validation UI](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#native-dom-validation-ui)

Just do this in your form:

```html
<form ngNativeValidate>
  ...
</form>
```

This will enable native DOM validation with Angular forms, such that the `invalid` and `valid` pseudo classes are applied for custom angular validations.