# CoreUI angular reactive form validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, core-ui

i'm trying to build a form with validation using [CoreUI](https://coreui.io/angular/) (free) and angular 11 but I have an issue on the input component.

here is my controller (the form definition part):

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  firstname: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  saleForces: []
});
```

and here the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" class="was-validated" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()" novalidate>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" />
    {{ firstname.errors | json }} {{ firstname.invalid }}
    <div *ngIf="firstname.invalid"
         class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="firstname.errors.required">
        Name is required.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="firstname.errors.minlength">
        Name must be at least 4 characters long.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

but the form-control is still valid!
[image: form control]

Comment: That looks all fine. Do you get any errors in the console log?

Comment: no, the console log is clean

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
the css in CoreUI act on :valid and :invalid pseudo-class and these classes are added only if you use the [html5 validation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) , but angular add the ng-valid and ng-invalid class.

so is needed a workaround to translate the angular classes in the html5 pseudo-classes.
this solution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620118/3645186)